# how to create a two column layout for header top links in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

> i use magento 2.1.1. i want to create a top links in left or right side above header.
>   i attaching the following image of..[image: My Html page]
>   i want to add a links like **All flowers**, **All cakes**, etc to left side and **delivery**, **currency** in right side at the top of **header**, but in Magento 2 layout overview link, display in right side. 
>   how i add a left side **header links** in **magento 2...?**
>   please help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to your default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <container name="header-category" label="Header Category" as="header-category" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-category-wrapper" before="-">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header_category" as="header_category" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/categories.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create one file named categories.phtml under

> app/design/frontend/[Your_Package]/[Your_Theme]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/categories.phtml

Now here you can add your code. After this you can manage that particular container whose class is "header-category-wrapper" by css.

```
.header-category-wrapper{float:left;}
```

And add some more styling and adjustment according to your requirement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but all css of header was removed. i adding a cutom css was not applied, i add a <css src="css/styles.css"/> in head tag.

Comment: Don't remove the existing content of default.xml only add the code I have written here.